# iterating through elements in a column fo preprocessing using python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, machine-learning, jupyter

i have been using a data set on housing for Machine learning.
while trying to reduce the dimensions of the dataset i wanted to merge 2 columns namely 'yr_built' and 'yr_renovated' to a new column 'age' ( of the house) .

i am trying to create a new column age from 2 predefined columns ((year_built) and (year_renovated)). the column of year renovated has values like year (eg 1991 if renovated) or 0 if not renovated.

The logic i am trying to use here is that If renovation happened, age of building is current year - year of renovation i.e.

[age = 2019 - year_renovated]

If no renovation has taken place: age of building is current year - year of construction i.e.

[age = 2019 - year_built]

[the image of the ppnew data is displayed in following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX2qP.png)

I have tried to use a for loop for the same and the code is as follows:

```py
[enter image description here][1]

for i in pp['age']:
    if pp['yr_renovated'] = 0:
        ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_built']
    else:
       ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_renovated']
```

and i also tried to use

```py
for i in pp['age']:
    if pp['yr_renovated'] == 0: #truth value
        ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_built']
    else:
       ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_renovated']
```

the error says boolean error

plz help with the code.

thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to find `age1(=2019 - year_built)` where `year_renovated` is 0?

Comment: i am trying to create a new column age from 2 predefined columns ((year_built) and (year_renovated)). the column of year renovated has values like year (eg 1991 if renovated) or 0 if not renovated.

The logic i am trying to use here is that
If renovation happened,
age of building is current year - year of renovation i.e. [age = 2019 - year_renovated]

If no renovation has taken place:
age of building is current year - year of construction i.e. [age = 2019 - year_built]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exaclty you want to achieve (if something different, add expected output to question), but it looks to me like that:

```
import numpy as np

ppnew['age1'] = np.where(pp['yr_renovated']==0, 2019 - pp['yr_built'] , 2019 - pp['yr_renovated'])
```

I assume that `ppnew` dataframe already exists.

Comment: thank you for the response. i have detailed the issue elaborately in the description. yes ppnew does exist.

Comment: i am trying to create a new column age from 2 predefined columns ((year_built) and (year_renovated)). the column of year renovated has values like year (eg 1991 if renovated) or 0 if not renovated. The logic i am trying to use here is that If renovation happened, age of building is current year - year of renovation i.e. [age = 2019 - year_renovated] If no renovation has taken place: age of building is current year - year of construction i.e. [age = 2019 - year_built]